# Is it possible to force AVPlayer stop playing video externally (on Apple TV)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, airplay

I have iOS application that plays video through HTTP via AVPlayer.

I have MPVolumeView that allows to select airplay device to stream current playback to.

But now I need to have ability to programmatically stop video streaming, and continue playback on AVPlayer's video layer in my application on iPad screen. (Like MPVolumeView's button does, but programmatically)

Please, help me, I tried to find solution myself and with the help of google but I am not able to solve this problem:(

Is it really possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'd have to read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012555) reference on programming multiple displays.

But in this specific situation I think, you are looking for `[UIScreen screens]` which returns an `NSArray` of `UIScreen` objects. The `UIScreen` with index 0 is the internal display and the one with the index 1 is the Apple TV's display. From now on, according to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012555-CH3-SW1) documentation and its examples you only need to create a `UIWindow` which has the screen property of the `UIScreen` you want to display on. Then you can easily add layers, views, etc. to that UIWindow.

Comment: Thanks for references and help Rickye, It seems to be a key for solution, I'll try to use it and maybe it will solve my problem.
It's definitely worth researching!

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario, you don't need to program multiple displays directly.  You just need to tell iOS' video subsystem to stop using the other display...

`AVPlayer` has a property [`allowsExternalPlayback`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayer/allowsExternalPlayback) which you can set to `NO`.  This will disable playback on the external display.  Playback will continue on the player's original `AVPlayerLayer` within your application.

Comment: I've tried this, video playback is disabled on external display and continues to play in iPad screen, but audio still plays via external display

Comment: Yup... I also encounter this issue. The audio still plays via the external display. Did you find a solution for this? @AlexanderTkachenko

Comment: @KarenAnne Unfortunately no. I have some thoughts that 'video' playback via AVPlayer uses AVAudioSession to play sound, so when we disable allowsExternalPlayback, AVAudioSession uses it's own settings and continuous to play via external device. I think maybe it's also needed to configure AVAudioSession to disable airplay.

Comment: Did someone of you found a solution for this? I'm having the same issue that the audio keeps playing via the external display... thx!